# How to hook protocol,such as DiskIO and BlockIO,in UEFI?

Tags: hook, protocols, uefi

I want to develop a diskless product based on UEFI(the diskless product based on legacy BIOS has been popular for many years),but I has met one problem ----
To hook DiskIO Protocol and BlockIO Protocl is needed to filter some IO operations to replace the original protocols in UEFI,but I don't know the way to make this realized. So I wanna get answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register protocol notification event to get called after that protocols are published, and call gBS->ReinstallProtocolInterface to replace them with your hooked ones.

Comment: Thank u! But I still have a doubt that maybe there  are  many contoller handles to which a DiskIO protocol instance is attached. After hooking,how to guarantee to filter all the IO operations through DiskIO protocol on all the controller handles?

Comment: The hook here is global,how to realize it?

Comment: You will be notified each time a new DiskIo protocol is registered, and you need to hook every DiskIo on every handle to be able to filter all of them.

Comment: For an example of diskless UEFI-based system, see Intel Galileo and [it's BSP](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/23197/Intel-Quark-BSP).

Comment: I got a error of firmware when I had hooked BlockIo Protocol using ReinstallProtocolInterface in VMware workstation 12.1.1!  After I hooked BlockIo Protocol of an logical partition,the ReadBlocks function pointer of new BlockIo Protocol was called,but I hadn't called this obviously. I need your help now!